# How to change my header menu into full width?

Tags: html, css, menu

I've got a problem with my header menu. The menu div is inside a container (width 1240px) and the div is 100%. I would like to have a full green colored menu (like above from Stack Exchange).

Can I change it with CSS? Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Can you put the menu outside the container? The width of 100% relates to the parent element ( which here has a width of 1024px).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take the menu div out of the container and place it above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, you could use container-fluid, if not follow the answer of Jordan and move the menu out of the container

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your situation

```
<div class="container" width="1240px">
<div class="menu" width="100%">..</div>
</div>
```

You can either do the following

```
<div class="menu" width="100%">..</div> 
<div class="container" width="1240px">
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="menu" width="100%">..</div>
</div>
```